# Clarity on Windows 10 iot-core over-air-update options?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub, windows-iot-core-10

I'd written my own over-air-update for previous version of iot-core (with or without iot-hub). The recent auto-update of iot-core (10.0.14393.67) broke it. Now, looking once again for clarity on this crucial (out-of-box feature on debian) capability, I am more confused than ever. Who can answer:

1. [This post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/iot-hub-device-management-device-jobs/) talks about updating firmware via the iot-hub. Is firmware my (uwp) iot-core app (e.g. background task) or not?
2. [This post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/service/iot/updating-iot-core-apps) talks about oem deals from microsoft for iot-core commercialization (https://www.windowsforiotdevices.com/) which provide update capabilities. However, it is unclear about:

   - Is "option one" free? If not, what is the catch?
   - Are the update capabilities available in this "option one"

At best, we'd need a trade-off-set juxtaposition of the iot-hub vs. oem app-package-update scenarios since once a developer decides for one or the other paths, it is a major investment.

**Update**

What really matters here is clarity to companies/developers on the options and limitations regarding "over air updates" of:

1. Our Apps (Appx, headless, in our case. C#.) built in Visual Studio 2015.
2. The iot-core OS (automatic or scheduled...).
3. Ths iot-core OS WITH (or in conjunction with) our Apps.

These options, and their costs, are not clear. We are currently using the azure iot-hub (et. al.) and would like to leverage it as much as possible.

What happened, and what I am urgently trying to fix, is "3" above: I had an appx in the field and was using the /System32/oemcustomization.bat option to install new versions of my app via C:/windows/appinstall/...

This was working fine at all my remote sites for months. I was confident that all was stable. All of the sudden, my sites all wend offline. In my local laboratory, I could connect to my test systems where I noticed that Microsoft had done an automatic OS update of iot-core. There were breaking changes... and these changes are now of the nature that my previous over-air-update scheme no longer works even if I modify it -- there are security "fixes" that break my current approach and I see now way to salvage it yet.

Thus, what we really need from the PM is clarity on the above (1-3) items, and, at best, an complete, minimal example in C# for items 1-3.

Looking forward!

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be two current solution streams here, both highly volatile/preview as far as I can see:

1. windows-store oem track: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/store
2. iot-hub device management track: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/iot-hub-device-management-device-jobs/